# Pre-train BERT base for text classification

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transformer-model

I have a tweet corpus and I am trying to use BERT for classification. I have successfully pre-trained BERT using my corpus, and it has generated the checkpoint files. Now I need to use this new trained model, and add some more layers to it. 
I tried to use the "load_trained_model_from_checkpoint" function from keras_bert, but it's failing with error "cls/predictions/transform/dense/kernel not found in checkpoint". Can anyone please help me fix this bug. Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code on how you pre-trained ? Once you already trained the BERT using your custom corpus and saved it, the next time on you should use `keras.models.load_model("saved_model")` to load the models.

Comment: Also, you could add layers before saving the model. General flow could be load pre-trained BERT base model, add layer, train with custom data, save the trained models, load saved, use it to predict). You can find more details on how to fine-tune BERT for text classification here: https://pysnacks.com/machine-learning/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/#binary-text-classification-using-bert  . It also provides working Google Colab code that can run on GPU.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some tips on how to use predictions based on a pretrained model in this library, [lazy-text-predict](https://github.com/lemay-ai/lazyTextPredict)! It might also help you with implementation of your text classifier in general.

```
text='my text to classify'
model=BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('/content/bert-base-uncased_model')
tokenizer=BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
text_classification= transformers.pipeline('sentiment-analysis',
                                            model=model, 
                                            tokenizer=tokenizer)
y=text_classification(text)[0]
print(y)
```